# Getting an "out of range value" on a conversion of varchar data type to a datetime data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The error occurs while stored procedure is executing a function to convert `varchar` data  type into into a `datetime` data type

Since I cannot debug the SQL statement where the error is occurring, is there a way that I can print the values of the data that which is being converted in the store procedure and causing the out of range error?

Or, how can I find out why is the error occurring?

**Code:**

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MONTH VARCHAR(2) = SUBSTRING(@CASH_DATE_FROM,5,2)
    DECLARE @YEAR VARCHAR(4) = SUBSTRING(@CASH_DATE_FROM,1,4)
    DECLARE @WORK_FILE VARCHAR(80) = ''
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(3000) = ''

    -- Create Report Tables

    IF (@REPORT_TYPE = '2')
    BEGIN
        SET @WORK_FILE = 'RRS.STG_PST_COLLECTIONS_REVENUE_01'
        -- print data
        --  select column  from table where column not like '%[^0-9]%';
        -- Select records from Staging 1
        SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO ' + @WORK_FILE + 
                   ' SELECT 
                     REPORT_PERIOD, DATA_SET
                    ,RRS.udfConvertDatetime(START_CASH_DATE)START_CASH_DATE
                    ,RRS.udfConvertDatetime(END_CASH_DATE)END_CASH_DATE, TAT_GRP  
                    ,RRS.udfConvertDatetime(CASH_DATE)CASH_DATE, REMIT_ID
                    ,RRS.udfConvertDatetime(TRANSACTION_DATE)TRANSACTION_DATE, PAYMENT_AMT 
                    ,TAT, TAT_IND, ACCT_NBR, ORIGINAL_IND, CASH_TRANS_DAY_IND, TRANSFERED_TO 
                    ,TRANSFERED_TO_TAT_IND, TRANSFERED_TO_ACCT_NBR, TRANSFERED_FROM, TRANSFERED_FR_TAT_IND
                    ,TRANSFERED_FR_ACCT_NBR, AR_RETURN_IND, PYMT_TRANS_ID, UNAPPLIED_APPLIED_IND 
                    ,BACKED_OUT_DC_REF_IND, FUND_CODE, BATCH, ONLINE_ENTERED_IND, REMIT_TYPE_CODE, EFT_SW


                     FROM ' + 'RRS.LBS_28_STAGING_' +  @MONTH + '_' + @YEAR + '_1' +
                    ' WHERE AR_RETURN_IND = ' + '''A'''
        EXEC (@SQL)

        -- Select records from Staging 2        
        SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO ' + @WORK_FILE + 
                   ' SELECT 
                     REPORT_PERIOD, DATA_SET
                    ,RRS.udfConvertDatetime(START_CASH_DATE)START_CASH_DATE
                    ,RRS.udfConvertDatetime(END_CASH_DATE)END_CASH_DATE, TAT_GRP  
                    ,RRS.udfConvertDatetime(CASH_DATE)CASH_DATE, REMIT_ID
                    ,RRS.udfConvertDatetime(TRANSACTION_DATE)TRANSACTION_DATE, PAYMENT_AMT 
                    ,TAT, TAT_IND, ACCT_NBR, ORIGINAL_IND, CASH_TRANS_DAY_IND, TRANSFERED_TO 
                    ,TRANSFERED_TO_TAT_IND, TRANSFERED_TO_ACCT_NBR, TRANSFERED_FROM, TRANSFERED_FR_TAT_IND
                    ,TRANSFERED_FR_ACCT_NBR, AR_RETURN_IND, PYMT_TRANS_ID, UNAPPLIED_APPLIED_IND 
                    ,BACKED_OUT_DC_REF_IND, FUND_CODE, BATCH, ONLINE_ENTERED_IND, REMIT_TYPE_CODE, EFT_SW

                     FROM ' + 'RRS.LBS_28_STAGING_' +  @MONTH + '_' + @YEAR + '_2' +
                    ' WHERE AR_RETURN_IND = ' + '''A'''
        EXEC (@SQL)     

        -- Update TAT_GRP
        SET @SQL = 'UPDATE ' +  @WORK_FILE + 
                   ' SET TAT_GRP = (CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(TAT,1,1) = ' + '''S''' + ' THEN ' + '''SUA''' + ' ELSE ' + '''STF''' + ' END)' +
                    ' WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),START_CASH_DATE) = ' 
                  + CHAR(39) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),RRS.udfConvertDatetime(@CASH_DATE_FROM))+ CHAR(39)
                   + ' AND END_CASH_DATE = ' 
                  + CHAR(39)+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),RRS.udfConvertDatetime(@CASH_DATE_TO))+CHAR(39)
        EXEC (@SQL) 

    END
```

Comment: Can you post the code from the SP?

Comment: Can you post the *code* not a screenshot of the code?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you find the records which is having non numeric data:

```
select column  from table where column not like '%[^0-9]%';
```

Answer (score 0):

The date range for DATETIME datatype is **January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999**.
So first check whatever dates that you are passing lies between this date range. Also check if you passing invalid date like 31st April etc.

You can print the dynamic query that you are forming by using `PRINT` function.
eg. `PRINT @SQL`

Comment: Can you format your answers a bit better please? This is all rendered as code because of the extra spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert to `varchar`.

TRY THIS

```
dtadmi BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'+''''+@dt_frm+'''''+' ) AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'+''''+@dt_to+''''+').....

where @dt_frm,@dt_to=storedprocedure parameter
```